# Which character is depicted on the cover of Harley Quinn New 52 series?

Tags: dc, character-identification, the-new-52

On the cover shows a semi-cyborg character with Harley, but I can't find the information about him. Who is he? Supervillain/hero/normal character?

[image: One of the covers with him]

Comment: Lolled, I immediatly thought about doctor Nefarious from Despicable Me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sy Borgman](http://www.comicvine.com/syborg/4005-99395/) aka Syborg. He's a former secret government agent, now an elderly acerbic resident of a nursing home that Harley starts working in. Introduced in Issue 4, he was apparently involved in an explosion of a bomb in his working days, and had his lost body parts replaced with state-of-the-art cybernetic limbs. Unfortunately, they were state-of-the-art decades ago.

> He hires Harley to [help him eliminate some of his former contemporaries](http://www.geekedoutnation.com/review-harley-quinn-5/) in that issue.